# Review and revert edits in default version

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, editing, versioning

We have feature class in a versioned enterprise geodatabase. Unfortunately some unwanted edits were done directly in DEFAULT version.

The database was not compressed yet, base table is unaffected by these edits so far. Edits are for now only in delta tables. To makes things a bit more difficult archiving is also enabled as well as topology. So edits propagated into topology, and history tables.

Is there any way to review and ideally selectively, or completely revert edits done in DEFAULT version for the specific feature class?

Comment: It's important to understand that a "version" is just a named state. The state tree doesn't care what things are named, just about states. So what you need to do is inspect the state tree with respect to the affected feature class. The answer to your question is "Yes, of course," but it will involve obtaining intimate knowledge of the versioning model. Tech Support might have tools to make your task easier.

Comment: Do you have a version that doesn't have the changes (hasn't been reconciled)? Reconciling from it to a new version and posting that data, if possible, is an indirect way to undo changes.  As Vince mentioned, it is hard to explain the best way to do this without knowing what your versioning workflow is. To be careful, I would copy out the good data somewhere outside the EGDB so you can try again to restore it.

Comment: @danak Thank you, that would be great way to use version without changes. Unfortunately no, we don't have. Workflow is what we clearly must change - first of all ESRI itself mentions in the intro to versioning to not do edits directly on default version. Fair enough there is no tool officially available.